# Automated trading using MT4 webclient

Tags: mt4

Is it possible to use the MT4 webclient for automated trading? I.e. Can expert advisors be developed and executed in the MT4 webclient?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can , you can use EAs to perform specific algo and place trade at specific time or event